# Blazor error Type or namespace name 'App' could not be found

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I have migrate project from .NET 6 to .NET 7 preview 2, and now I have this output:

```
 error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'App' could not be found
```

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Preview
Version 17.2.0 Preview 2.1.

Comment: The error suggests the project can't find `App.razor`.  Try fully qualifying it in either program.cs for WASM or _hosts.html in Server.

Comment: App.razor is available and visual studio dont directly show this error i see this error in build output window(Blazor wasm)

Answer (score 1):

Go to your `Program.cs` and check if this line displays an error.

`builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");`

If you're using Visual Studio, go to that line and hit Alt + Enter to show the code suggestions. Check if it asks you to import the root namespace of your project. Example: if your project is named MyProject you might need to add `using Myproject` at the import section of the `Program.cs` file.

Comment: I test this case... but i assume this is .net 7 preview 2 bug when switch .net 6 to .net 7 preview 2

Comment: @SajjadArash does the error go if you switch back to .NET 6?

Comment: Yeah this error go after i switch back... :/

Answer (score 0):

Double check all installed nuget packages are also updated to the appropriate preview version that is compatible with .NET 7

Comment: yes in that version of .net 7 blazor have bugs